# How to implement iMovie Trimming View?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetexportsession, avcomposition

I need to merge multiple videos before that I want to trim Videos and place Text overlay over Videos. I want to create simply another iMovie app with all functionality. Could you please suggest any library is available in GitHub or please share your ideas on this, I will be grateful for you

Comment: This questions is too broad for stack overflow. Break down what you would like t do.  Apple and 3rd parties have plenty of guides on how to trim videos, how to add overlays, etc. When you face a specific problem, post some code and what is going wrong, and then we can help.

Comment: I am not able to split and trim videos like iMovie app, Could you please explain how can we accomplish  transition and splitting videos